# How to return a generic Promise type?

Tags: typescript, async-await, es6-promise

Basically, I have a Manifest class like below:

```
export interface SomeManifest {
  loadChildren: Promise<any>;
  name: string;
}
```

In the calling will be:

```
const mod = await manifest.loadChildren();
```

But I get the following error

> Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<{}>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]

If I change `loadChildren` to return `any`, then the error gone. Doing this way, it's very hard to know `loadChildren` is a function to return a promise or not. How can I use return `Promise` type without the above error?

Comment: This doesn't quite constitute a [mcve] as described by [ask].  Where is `manifest` declared?  If it is of type `SomeManifest`, I expect `manifest.loadChildren()` to be an error because `loadChildren` is not a function but a promise, but the error wouldn't be the one you've included.  If I change the type of `loadChildren` to be `loadChildren(): Promise<any>;` I don't expect any error with `await manifest.loadChildren()`.  Can you please produce something suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org)?  Good luck!

Comment: Thank @jcalz, it's my bad to not decorate loadChildren as a function.

Comment: This is due to multiple Promise declarations imported by different declaration modules.